# .loading css doesn't work from external stylesheet

Tags: css

I have a `.loading` css class defined, which only appears to work if I add it to the the page as internal css. It fails to generate the loading circle when I move it to my external `style.css` file.

**Here's what I do know:**

1. `style.css` is being loaded because the page is styled and I have also double checked via firebug.
2. I have tried adding `.loading` to a `.css` file of its own and loaded it and it still fails.
3. I don't have another `.loading` class defined in my `style.css` file
4. I have tried renaming `.loading` to `.loadingCircle` with no change (did this incase it conflicts with JQuery)

**My header files:**

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/js/jquery.js'></script>
<link href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/js/createDialog.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.tablesorter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/jquery.tablesorter.pager.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='includes/js/script.js'></script>
```

Comment: From your code block, did you miss an opening angle bracket `<` ? There's also a jquery-ui custom css file, is there any `.loading` class defined inside? Also, would be good if you can use a browser's inspector to check whether your css files are actually loaded.

Comment: @VKen: I failed to copy/paste the angle bracket, now added. Well, I labelled it as `.loadingCircle` and it still failed. I have already checked via firebug and confirmed that the css was loaded.

Comment: Could you also post your css, and the affected bit of html? Use a simple test case. Perhaps a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is good for demonstration and testing as well.

Comment: Phillip's answer below might yield some clues. Have you checked your firebug whether there is any overriding css styles for your declared css classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. While having another look at my css I discovered that it was an issue with the path to the loading image. I guess had I added it someone would have spotted it for me

My folder structure was such that:

```
 /css
 /images
 searchForm.php
 index.php
 edit.php
```

My .loading css inside `searchForm.php` had:

```
.loading {
       background:url('images/ajax-loader_thick.gif') no-repeat center center;
```

I missed doing this when I added it to my `style.css` file inside the `css` folder:

```
.loading {
       background:url('../images/ajax-loader_thick.gif') no-repeat center center;
```

Answer (score 1):

Move your css file after the jqueryui css import. Last one wins if they have the same specificity...